# Tracking multiple activity using google tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In the website  I have PDF, form to register, video
Scenario : Unregistered user comes to my website. Visitor/ User  during the session /visit 
Lands on a particular page in the website. After Landing on particular page how many user perform activity such as PDF download or register with the website or viewed the video. The activity may be single like user/visitor only downloaded the PDF or multiple activity such downloaded PDF as  well as watched video also. I want to have report in below format

```
Landing Page/First page     PDf download  form register      video viewed
Home Page                    3                0                  2
Xyz                          0                3                  0     Abc                          7                1                  0
```

In Omniture I can track this using evar which capture the session activity for the visit.How can i do the same with GA and GTM

Comment: You would create event based goals (events are success metrics in analytics) and create a custom report with the landing page as dimensions and goal completions for the various goals as metrics. Not sure if this wouldn't be a better fit for the webmaster's SO site, since there is very little programming involved.